# Getting the month number by month name with Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to return the month number passing the month name using MomentJS. For example if I pass "July" to moment() I would expect 7 to be returned.

After reading through the docs I tried several different ways, and this way came close...

```
console.log(moment().month("July"));
```

In the console, buried in the response I could see this...

```
_monthsParse: Array[7]
```

Could anyone please tell me how to return the month number using MomentJS correctly?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try :

```
moment().month("July").format("M");
```

Relevant documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/

```js
alert(moment().month("July").format("M"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 36):

Anybody looking to get month name from month number then you can try :

```
const number = 1; // 0 = Jan & 11 = Dec
moment().month(number).format("MMM"); // Feb
```

Use following to get full month name :

```
const number = 1; // 0 = January & 11 = December
moment().month(number).format("MMMM"); // February
```

Comment: Plus one.. It's funny that this is what I'm looking for and I just checked this question to get an idea.

Answer (score 6):

To use simple month number try this:

```
const month = 2 //Feb
moment(month, 'M').format('MMMM');
```

Answer (score 0):

````
##get month name in moment js with node js 
moment() give today date
format("DD-MMMM-YYYY") / output 18-May-2020
format("DD-MM-YYYY")  / output 18-05-2020
- sperator you can use / 

```
var moment = require('moment'); 

   m_date = moment().format("DD-MMMM-YYYY");
   console.log("moment date :", m_date)
```
##output
```
moment date : 18-May-2020

```
````

[Read Officail Docdescription here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/12-month/)